# How do I change the display for elements in a parent page with router in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I want to dynamically change the @media print styles of parent elements, while not changing the styles of these same elements for @media screen.

I have a parent page which displays multiple child components.

```
<header>
   <title></title>
   <navigation></navigation> 
</header>
<main>
   <banner></banner>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
<main>
```

I want to display a report on a page in the router portion via @media print that hides all the rest of the elements on the page - and just displays report.

I can add the following to the main style.scss

```
[data-report="should-be-printed"]
@media print {
    body: not([[data-report="should-be-printed"], [data-report="should-be-printed"] *) {
       display: none;
    }
    [data-report="should-be-printed"] {
       display: block;
    }
}
```

While this achieves what I want for this specific report, it hides all the other reports (pages displayed via router-outlet).

What I need is a way to modify the style:display setting for the various elements not displayed in the report for this specific page (i.e., do it via javascript), but NOT impact the other reports and their print preview functionality.

I have tried putting id="header" in the header tag and then using

```
const tempElement = document.getElementById('header');
tempElement.style.display = 'none';
```

to identify the various elements and hide them. However, this impacts the screen portion as well.

The end goal is to change the style ONLY for @media print.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could take is to use CSS media queries to target the print styles, and use JavaScript to toggle a class on the elements you want to hide during printing. Here's an example of how you might achieve this:

- In your CSS file, define a class for the elements you want to hide during printing:

  .hide-on-print {display: none;}
- Add the following code to your component:

  interface Window {
  matchMedia(mediaQuery: string): MediaQueryList;
  }

  ```
   const hiddenElements: NodeListOf<HTMLElement> = document.querySelectorAll('.hide-on-print');

   const mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
   mediaQueryList.addEventListener('change', () => {
     if (mediaQueryList.matches) {
       hiddenElements.forEach((element) => {
         element.classList.add('hide-on-print');
       });
     } else {
       hiddenElements.forEach((element) => {
         element.classList.remove('hide-on-print');
       });
     }
   });
  ```

This code selects all elements with the hide-on-print class, and adds an event listener to the matchMedia() method to listen for changes in the media query. When the media query matches the print styles, the class is added to the element, and when it doesn't match, the class is removed.

- In your HTML, add the class="hide-on-print" attribute to the elements you want to hide during printing:

```html
<header class="hide-on-print">
  <!-- header contents -->
</header>
<main class="hide-on-print">
  <!-- main contents -->
</main>
```

Comment: I like the approach, but it doesn't work.  The parent elements are still visible in both screen and print media forms.